# Ruby Gem ice_cube. How could I store a recurrence rule in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ice-cube

I might save a schedule in db `repeats = schedule.to_hash` or `repeats = schedule.to_yaml`
then use it from db `schedule = repeats.from_hash`

But I need to know what is a rule. For example, if it is repeated weekly, how could I store a rule in db or how could I know rule from schedule? Is it some methods like .to_hash and .from_hash for rules?

Answer (score 0):

A `Schedule` can have many *reoccurring* and *exception* rules. You could get them by doing `schedule.recurrence_rules` or `schedule.exception_rules`. In addition there can be *recurrence times* and *exception times* as well. (For detailed information on what these rules are, head to: https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube#quick-introductions)

Hence, it is a best practice to just store a serialized `Schedule` in the database and not a particular rule.

If you wish, methods like `to_hash` and `to_yaml` are available on a rule as well:

```
irb(main)> schedule.recurrence_rules.first.to_yaml
=> "---\n:validations: {}\n:rule_type: IceCube::DailyRule\n:interval: 1\n"

irb(main)> schedule.recurrence_rules.first.to_hash
=> {:validations=>{}, :rule_type=>"IceCube::DailyRule", :interval=>1}
```